# OpenLayers: how to save added point in server side

Tags: openlayers-2, point

- I'm new in OpenLayers.
- I have simple application, which use a picture as map,
- on this picture users can add, move, or delte point, and then save.
- I have implemented adding, moving, deleting functionalities, only
  except save.
- codes are in below :

[codes here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mr7d/33/)

- anyone who knows how to save change on server side? save to database,
  file?

Comment: Repeated question? "How do I edit info feature attributes in geoserver with openlayer" (http://goo.gl/7GVbz)

Answer (score 2):

I found a cool sample that illustrates the handling. Take a look at this (the source code :-D) http://edgemaster.dev.openstreetmap.org/oldemo/10.htm

Your vector layer needs a server part two handle the persistence. The save strategy only triggers the write back.

```
/* from the sample source */
var scribble = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Scribble", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "featureserver/featureserver.cgi/scribble",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save({auto: true})],
    projection: wgs
});
map.addLayer(scribble);
```

Comment: hi, thank your replay firstly.
I've tried whole day on this, current the source as in below:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Mr7d/42/
I can load data use protocol now, but still didn't try out how to save data, save function is triggered, but how to do next, any suggestion on this?

Comment: I know it can be implemented by sending a ajax request, but want to learn how to use openlayers

Comment: after adding saveStrategy to pointLayer, now the commit function can be triggered when clicking save button, source :
http://jsfiddle.net/7Mr7d/43/
how to send request in commit function using openlayers way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right but imo if you add the right URL to your vector layer it automatic writes the data back. But you need a related server part. For instance a wfs server or a script that handles the request server side. The post from rashad give you some sample components for that

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a WFS-T service. OpenLayers does support WFS, WFS-T and is based on ajax request because of javascript ion of OL. The steps are as follows:

Setup the following:

1. PostgreSQL / PostGIS.
2. WFS server - (Geoserver,MapServer,tinyOWS).
3. WFS Client ofcourse, openlayers

tinyOWS is small and easy
A full tutorial from start can be found [here](http://mapserver.org/trunk/tinyows/openlayershowto.html)

Comment: actually I can place ajax codes in commit function to save data without WFS-T, just want to learn the way openlayers does